# Destructured arguments under optional function arguments in typescript throw error

Tags: typescript

```
interface Type1 {
  attr1: string;
  attr2: string;
}
interface Type2 {
  attr1: string;
  attr2: string;
  attr3: string; // extra attribute
}

function fn(config: Type1 | Type2): void {
  // Property 'attr3' does not exist on type 'Type1 | Type2'.ts(2339)
  const { attr1, attr2, attr3 } = config;
  console.log(attr1);
  console.log(attr2);
  console.log(attr3);
}
```

Error code show before. And I know there is a solution that add optional attribute in `attr3`. But as far as I'm concerned this solution is not good. Because as matter of fact there only exist 2 situations either `Type1` or `Type2`. In a word, optional way is not readability. How can I fix it in advanced way?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Because your types say that you *do not* have `attr3`, so what value do you expect when trying to get a non-existing attribute?

Comment: Just remove `Type1` and make `attr3` optional or https://catchts.com/unions#safe_union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply check if `attr3` exists in the object

```js
function fn(config: Type1 | Type2): void {
  if ('attr3' in config) {
    const {
      attr1,
      attr2,
      attr3
    } = config;
  } else {
    const {
      attr1,
      attr2
    } = config;
  }
}
```

Or you could use a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```js
function IsType2(config: Type1 | Type2): config is Type2 {
  return (config as Type2).attr3 !== undefined;
}

function fn(config: Type1 | Type2): void {
  if (IsType2(config)) {
    const {
      attr1,
      attr2,
      attr3
    } = config;
  } else {
    const {
      attr1,
      attr2
    } = config;
  }
}
```

Or if we **really** wanted to destructure only once, we could create a join type, though we would be coercing the type rather than inferring it.

```js
function fn(config: Type1 | Type2): void {
  const {
    attr1,
    attr2,
    attr3
  } = config as Type1 & Type2;
}
```

As far as I know, there's no way to directly destructure a union type

Comment: And how do you use those variables outside the `if`? Or do you just copy/paste the code in each branch?

Comment: You could copy/paste the code in each branch, or you could extract the processing logic into isolated functions to reduce WET code. That seems slightly beyond the scope of the question though.

Comment: The question is how to handle it better. I'm not sure an `if` fits that criteria.

Comment: OP presented adding `attr3` to `Type1` as their only other known solution. Then asked for a solution in an "advanced" way. "advanced" doesn't mean better, so I just provided the remaining alternatives. IMO it does fit the criteria, though really only OP could confirm/deny if it meets their criteria.

Comment: Wasn't aware that advanced meant "worse". I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: "advanced" doesn't mean "worse" and you know that. If you don't like my answer, you can simply downvote it, that's the system. I'm trying to help, and if you think it's irrelevant, you can try make sure my answer isn't seen. I'm not sure why our discussion has ended in such sarcasm. It doesn't really seem warranted, regardless I still appreciate the input you've given thus far.

Comment: "*"advanced" doesn't mean "worse" and you know that.*" The `if` version I count as worse. Yet, you seem adamant it is at least as good, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the same result when missing `attr3` attribute as with `js` code you can just cast config type to intersection of types:

```typescript
interface Type1 {
  attr1: string;
  attr2: string;
}
interface Type2 {
  attr1: string;
  attr2: string;
  attr3: string; // extra attribute
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

function fn(config: Type1 | Type2): void {
  // Property 'attr3' does not exist on type 'Type1 | Type2'.ts(2339)
  const { attr1, attr2, attr3 } = config as UnionToIntersection<Parameters<typeof fn>[0]>;
  console.log(attr1);
  console.log(attr2);
  console.log(attr3);
}

fn({ attr1: '', attr2: '' })
```

or just to `... = config as Type1 & Type2;` if you don't mind some inflexibility.

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9Gkm)